# JavaScript is not running in Mozila Firefox, only runs in IE

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function del_rcd(param) 
{
    if(confirm("Do you really want to delete it")) 
    {
        window.location = 'controller/del_task_ctl.php?param='+param;
    }
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function popup(id)
{
window.open("detail.php?tid="+id, "Preview","width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes");
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function popupcomp(id)
{
window.open("edit_task.php?tid="+id, "Preview","width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes");
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function popupclose(id)
{
window.open("close.php?qid="+id, "Preview","width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is not running What do you see?

Comment: I see no code that will execute here... are you missing some of the sample code?

Comment: What is not working? Why are you separating all these functions in different script tags?

Comment: Why are you using HTML 3.2? (The type attribute become mandatory and the language attribute was deprecated a decade ago)

Answer (score 2):

Is JavaScript [disabled in Firefox](http://mistered.us/tips/javascript/firefox.shtml)?

Comment: Please enable your javascript in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Just as a side-note. The "language" attribute is quite obsolete ([See point 7](http://perfectionkills.com/optimizing-html/#markup_smells)). Instead write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I just made this quick test under OSX Firefox and it just works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function del_rcd(param){
        if(confirm("Do you really want to delete it")) 
        {
            window.location = 'controller/del_task_ctl.php?param='+param;
        }
    }

    function popup(id)
    {
        window.open("detail.php?tid="+id, "Preview","width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes");
    }

    function popupcomp(id)
    {
        window.open("edit_task.php?tid="+id, "Preview","width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes");
    }

    function popupclose(id)
    {
        window.open("close.php?qid="+id, "Preview","width=600,height=500,scrollbars=yes");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" Text="Click me" onclick="del_rcd('test')"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally what I always recommend web devs is to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and optionally [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/). This is a must especially when you deal with JavaScript. Firebug automatically shows you syntax or JavaScript runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting a form to this script by calling these js function
but submit button only works in IE and on all other browsers Submit button is not working

Comment: In the future, please edit your original question instead of posting an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking you're lucky ;) Most people have the opposite problem: everything works on Webkit browsers and Firefox, but not under IE ;)